# Bash: Second `elif` ignored

Tags: bash

I've searched over the net and stackoverflow and didn't see one of that, so I felt like asking here.

The following bash script will never hit the 2nd `elif`, that is, when you enter a string between 4 and 63 characters:

```
myglobvar="not important"
while true; do
  echo -n "Enter your string: "
  read newname

  if [ ${#newname} -eq 0 ]; then
    echo meep
    break
  elif [ ${#newname} -gt 63 ]; then
    echo "Warning: truncating name to 63 characters."
    myglobvar="${newname::63}"
    myglobvar="${sv_name//\"/'}"
    break
  elif [ ${#newname} -ge 4 ]; then
    myglobvar="${newname//\"/'}"
    break
  else
    if [ ${#newname} -ge 4 ]; then
      echo "what!?"
    fi
    echo "Invalid name input.[[ ${#newname} -ge 4 ]]"
  fi
done
```

This puzzled me a lot because it looks so correct, runs fine, and code highlighting -- at least in Notepad++ -- accepts it:

[image: syntax highlight working with the code above]

Running the code and typing anything between 4 and 63 characters will produce the following output:

```
Enter your string: a longer text
what!?
Invalid name input.[[ 13 -ge 4 ]]
```

Which is very very puzzling, as the 2nd test matches that the string is longer than 4 chars, and the length imprinted shows it is 13! What the?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the magic is, for a change, in the single quotes.

```
myglobvar="not important"
while true; do
  echo -n "Enter your string: "
  read newname

  if [ ${#newname} -eq 0 ]; then
    echo meep
    break
  elif [ ${#newname} -gt 63 ]; then
    echo "Warning: truncating name to 63 characters."
    myglobvar="${newname::63}"
    myglobvar="${sv_name//\"/\'}" # escaped single quote
    break
  elif [ ${#newname} -ge 4 ]; then
    myglobvar="${newname//\"/\'}" # escaped single quote again
    break
  else
    if [ ${#newname} -ge 4 ]; then
      echo "what!?"
    fi
    echo "Invalid name input.[[ ${#newname} -ge 4 ]]"
  fi
done
```

Albeit the string being surrounded in double quotes, and requiring the double quotes to be escaped within the variable, the single quotes must follow within the variable bracers, or the variable substitution just becomes:

```
}"
    break
  elif [ ${#newname} -ge 4 ]; then
    myglobvar="${newname//\"/
```

Completely "encapsulating" the `elif` code.

And the Bash script will run fine, as both the single and double quotes are properly closed.

Add another similar `elif` (or `else` for what it is worth), with that double quotes substitution, and you should get `unexpected EOF` errors.